# What is the meaning of the phrase, I'm partial to your abracadabra?

Tags: phrase-requests, slang, dialects

On Ian Dury's first album, there is a song titled, I'm partial to your Abracadabra.
The song, as all of Durys' songs is filled with lots of London slang, most of which is recognisable. However, i would like to know if anyone can tell me the meaning of the song's title

Comment: is it Abracadabra?

Comment: Yeah, soz about that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because song interpretation is outside the scope of the site.

Comment: @jimm101, I've seen lots of questions with an close or exact formal resemblance  to this one but where the subject matter came from a recognized literary work.  Beware of snobbery, it sometimes jumps on us from behind.

Comment: @Aethelbald I vote to close those too. Scope is scope. There are other places for interpretation. EL&U isn't it.

Comment: That is a reasonable, then.  So where is the scope defined? And yes, I should have read it first.

Comment: @Aethelbald The use of English in 'recognized literary works' is more likely to influence the development of the language and/or to manifest its aspects that may otherwise not be obvious, than the isolated cases of its intentionally whimsical use that one often finds in songs. It is not snobbery to regard that as a difference that is relevant to the purposes of ELU StackExchange.

Comment: @jsw29 "The use of English in 'recognized literary works' is more likely to influence the development of the language..."  How do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

**Abracadabra** [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abracadabra), [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abracadabra) and [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abracadabra)

> is an incantation used as a magic word in stage magic tricks ...

These are definitions of the word.  I am not sure what the author of the song intended but I suspect something similar.  Artists make liberal use of poetic license!

Comment: POB answers are not what are required.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth pardon ... POB?

Comment: Primarily Opinion Based is a specific reason why a question should be closed; answers of the sort, however good, do not fit here.

Answer (score 2):

It just means magic, I'm partial to your magic, but Abracadabra, a metonym for magic, scans better.